# JavaScript - window.moveBy not working

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, just learning about the window object.
I'm trying to make a simple script that will move the browser window 10 pixels in a direction, when one of the arrow keys is pressed.

I've verified that the event handler works, the key codes are correct, the moveScreen() function is being executed and the conditional within it works too.
So why won't the screen move???
I've tested in Firefox and Chrome so far.

```
function moveScreen(direction) {
    'use strict';

    if (direction === 'up') window.moveBy(0, -10);
    if (direction === 'right') window.moveBy(10, 0);
    if (direction === 'down') window.moveBy(0, 10);
    if (direction === 'left') window.moveBy(-10, 0);
}


function handleKeyDown(e) {
    'use strict';

    e = e || window.event;
    const key = e.keyCode;

    switch (key) {
        case 38:
            moveScreen('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            moveScreen('right');
            break;
        case 40:
            moveScreen('down');
            break;
        case 37:
            moveScreen('left');
            break;
    }
}


window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
    document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
}
```

This is the HTML file, it simply includes the script in the body:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="moveWindow.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only move pop-up windows that you have opened yourself from another page.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the description of moveBy on MDN here [MDN moveBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveBy) you will see that what you are trying is probably not possible.

> Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to move a window in a browser, according to the following rules:
>
> 1. You can't move a window or tab that wasn’t created by `window.open`.
> 2. You can't move a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
"You can't move a window that you haven't created yourself on another page."

Thanks Juhana.

So the quickest way I've found to get this to work is to open the console in a browser and open the HTML file there:

```
window.open('moveWindow.html')
```

If that opens a new tab, just click and drag the title of the window away from the one that was already open, focus the document and you're all good.